# How to costumize MultiSelect for MSForms.ListBox VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

Hi I want to achieve the following:

I have UserForm with a ListBox in it. This ListBox should have the following selection behaviour:

This is my Listbox:

[image]

## 1 MouseClick Toggles selection

[image]

## 2 MoveOver the item while holding the mouse button clicked will toggle selection

[image]

Unfortunately this behaviour is not matched by the 3 selectable MultiSelect properties.

**0- fmMultiSelectSingle**

- Not able to multiselect

**1-fmMultiSelectMulti**

Pretty close but:

- the ListItems get deselected when the mouse is not over the item anymore while holding the button down.

**2-fmMultiSelectExtended**

Also pretty close but:

- when you click somewhere else when the items are selected all items will deselect

## In summary the goal is to manually toggle all items with either clicking on them or moveing over them while the mouse is clicked

I have tried to do it with the ListBox_Change Event but I cannot figure out how..

This is the code I tried:

UserForm in General:

```
Private Type TView
    SelectedCol As Collection
    EventsDisabled As Boolean
End Type

Private this As TView

Public Property Get SelectedCol() As Collection
    Set SelectedCol = this.SelectedCol
End Property
Public Property Set SelectedCol(ByVal value As Collection)
    Set this.SelectedCol = value
    'Validate
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set SelectedCol = New Collection
counter = 0
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To OptionList.ListCount
    SelectedCol.Add Me.OptionList.Selected(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

The UpdateSelectedCol Sub:

```
Sub UpdateSelectedCol()
Dim i As Integer
Dim bo As Boolean
For i = OptionList.ListCount To 1
    SelectedCol.Remove (i)
Next i
For i = 1 To OptionList.ListCount
    SelectedCol.Add OptionList.Selected(i - 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

ListBox_Change Event:

```
Private Sub OptionList_Change()
Dim i As Integer
If this.EventsDisabled = False Then
    this.EventsDisabled = True
    GO_btn.Enabled = ISSelected(Me.OptionList)
    
    ' keep selected until changed
    For i = 1 To Me.OptionList.ListCount
        If SelectedCol.Item(i) Then
            Me.OptionList.Selected(i) = True
        End If
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print SelectedCount(Me.OptionList)
    UpdateSelectedCol
End If
this.EventsDisabled = False
End Sub
```

So what I tried was the following: When the Selection gets changed it will compare if that element was selected before and will keep it. This doesn't Change the MultiSelect behaviour a bit. It should in my opinion at least keep all items selcted that have been selected once.

EDIT: Added some pictures and code as example what I tried, and how it should function.

Comment: How do you wish to clear selections made in error (User wise)?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I don't know if I understand you correctly. I understand the following: What should be done if the user wants to deselect a item in the listbox?  In this case the user clicks the item which should toggle it. Or if there is a bunch of items selected he should be able to move over all of them while holding the mouse down.

Comment: You should put the question and what you've worked through before the pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I figured it out:

First you start with 1-MultiSelectMulti as a ListBox property. Than you add the following code to your userform:

## Solution

```
Private Sub OptionList_Change()
Dim i As Integer
If Not this.EventsDisabled Then
    this.EventsDisabled = True
    GO_btn.Enabled = ISSelected(Me.OptionList)
    
    ' MAIN SOLUTION ************************************************

    ' if has changed keep odl value when not = to listindex
    For i = 1 To Me.OptionList.ListCount
        If Me.OptionList.Selected(i - 1) <> SelectedCol.Item(i) And Not i - 1 = Me.OptionList.ListIndex Then
            ToggleItem (i)
        End If

    ' MAIN SOLUTION END ************************************************
        
    UpdateSelectedCol
    this.EventsDisabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

The great clue was the `.ListIndex` Property which tells you where the "Cursor" is in the list. It is also where your mouse will be when holding the mouse down. So all one has to do is:

**If the value of one listitem has changed and the listindex is not equal to the index of the changed item then toggle the item back to the initial state.**

## Prerequisists

```
Private Type TView
    SelectedCol As Collection
    EventsDisabled As Boolean
End Type

Private this As TView

Public Property Get SelectedCol() As Collection
    Set SelectedCol = this.SelectedCol
End Property
Public Property Set SelectedCol(ByVal value As Collection)
    Set this.SelectedCol = value
    'Validate
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set SelectedCol = New Collection
counter = 0
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To OptionList.ListCount
    SelectedCol.Add Me.OptionList.Selected(i - 1)
Next i

End Sub


Sub ToggleItem(i As Integer)
    Me.OptionList.Selected(i - 1) = Not Me.OptionList.Selected(i - 1)
End Sub

Sub UpdateSelectedCol()
this.EventsDisabled = True
Dim i As Integer
Dim bo As Boolean
For i = OptionList.ListCount To 1 Step -1
    SelectedCol.Remove (i)
Next i
For i = 1 To OptionList.ListCount
    SelectedCol.Add OptionList.Selected(i - 1)
Next i
this.EventsDisabled = False
End Sub
```

You need the prerequisits in the same userform for it to work. `UpdateSelectedCol` and `toggleitem` are pretty easy to reconstruct I think.